# How to render double curly braces in directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a back end validation integration with AngularJS. I need to display an error message right beside the control. The error message comes from back end. And the control is rendered by a directive template. I tried putting a span for an error message along with the control in the template, but I ran into an embarrassing situation.

Here's the code:

```js
var myDirective = angular.module('myDirective', []);
myDirective.directive("textquestion", function() {
    return {
        template: '<input id="{{questionNumber}}" name="{{questionNumber}}" type="text" /><span ng-show="errors[{{questionNumber}}]">{{error[questionNumber]}}</span>',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            questionNumber: 'questionNumber'
        }
    };
})
```

As you can see, I want to render `{{errors['1001']}}` in html, with '1001' being the actual questionNumber, so the error message can be binded. But in current code, since `errors['1001']` is empty at the time of rendering, this part will render nothing in html.

Can anyone help me with how to render actual `{{errors['1001']}}` in html? Or is there any better way to do this? Please keep in mind that the control is dynamically generated, so the questionNumber needs to be dynamic. And this error message comes from back end, so the binding needs to happen after the rendering.

Thank you！

Comment: As I gaze into my crystal ball...I see...`$compile`...is in your future.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? You won't need $compile because directives automatically do that with templates. But yeah as mentioned in the answer by @rob, you have some syntax issues.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I will try to learn about $compile.

Comment: @ribsies Thanks for the help. I've corrected my syntax issue. I think I got this issue because when we need to mix usage of template and directive template I got confused and wasn't sure where to put what. Turns out I mis-placed this span.

Comment: @magicbacon - np, but keep in mind `$compile` is for special situations in directives. It's a useful tool but may not be appropriate in this situation...I didn't dig too deeply into your problem.  It's the sort of question where `$compile` comes up though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the {{}} in your `ng-show`. What you pass into `ng-show` is already an expression

```
<span ng-show="errors[questionNumber]">{{errors[questionNumber]}}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that I shouldn't put my validation error in the directive template. Once it was moved out, the problem comes quite easy. And what you pointed out was also correct. Thank you for your help!